# How to I remove the white space between overridable="true" and default using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

```
 <Property name="wt.99999" overridable="true"

        default="ext.listner.services.ListnerService/ext.listner.services.ListnerService"/>
```

I want to remove the space using shell script.

I write this code.

```
filename2=CECWT.xconf
c=wt.99999
c1=ext.listner.services.ListnerService
grep -w "$c\|$c1" $filename2 > output.txt
cat output.txt | trim
```

I want output :

```
<Property name="wt.99999" overridable="true" default="ext.listner.services.ListnerService/ext.listner.services.ListnerService"/>
```

Comment: `trim` is not a standard command; what does it do?

Comment: @Shr: You obviously do **not** want to remove the whitespace at this place, because in your desired output, there **is** a single space betwen `true"` and `default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this GNU sed command:

```
sed '/overridable=/N; N; s/\n\s*/ /g' your_file
```

It finds any line with containing the string 'overridable=' and then reads in
the next 2 lines (`N; N`) since in your example there is a blank line before
the one you want. Then removes the newline characters and any trailing space
`\n\s*`, replacing them with spaces, resulting in a single joined line. (Note
this command will only work for the case of a single blank line between the two
lines you want joined!)

If you want to do the replacement in-place (i.e. overwrite the contents of the
your_file, you can add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '/overridable=.*/N; N; s/\n\s*/ /g' your_file
```

This page https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html explains sed very well if you
want to learn it.

#### Trying the command

When I test the command on a file called 'your_file' which has the contents:

```
 <Property name="wt.99999" overridable="true"

        default="ext.listner.services.ListnerService/ext.listner.services.ListnerService"/>
```

I get:

```
 <Property name="wt.99999" overridable="true" default="ext.listner.services.ListnerService/ext.listner.services.ListnerService"/>
```

Comment: Which of the two commands did you use? the one with or without the `-i` flag? The one without the `-i` flag will out print to stdout, it will not alter the original file in any way.

Comment: i tried both but they reflecting the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure how that can be since I also tried them on my machine (results updated in the answer). Is the file you're trying it on have the same contents as I show in my update?

Comment: cat output.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r"  ---> i tried this

Comment: <Propertyname="wt.99999"overridable="true"default="ext.listner.services.ListnerService/ext.listner.services.ListnerService"/>

Comment: but it shows output like this. Again need to add space

Comment: The `\n` escape is not portable to all `sed` dialects. `\s` is even less likely to be portable. This looks quite specific to GNU `sed`.

Comment: @tripleee you're right - I added the GNU spec to the answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Shr `tr -d "\t\n\r"` is not part of my answer.. I gave you a GNU sed command to try.

Comment: `<Propertyname="wt.99999"overridable="true"default="ext.listner.services.ListnerService/ext.listner.services.ListnerService"/>` ---> Then que is that how to add sapce after 99999 and true

Answer (score 1):

`grep` alone does not seem like a very good tool for this. If your input is proper XML, using a real XML tool to reformat it is probably the way to go.  But if you just need to clean something up quickly, try this simple Awk script:

```sh
awk '/<Property name="wt.99999"/ { printf "%s", $0; isprop=1; next }
    /^[ \t]*$/ && isprop { next; }
    { isprop=0 } 1' CECWT.xconf >output.txt
```

The `1` at the end prints the input line with newline and all. We special-case the line which matches the first regex to print that without the newline. We then add a state variable to also skip any lines with only whitespace on them (or nothing at all) until we find a line which doesn't match either regex.

This will still leave whitespace from the end of the property line and whitespace from the beginning of the following line; trimming that complicates the script slightly, but not by much.

```sh
awk '/<Property name="wt.99999"/ { printf "%s", $0; isprop=1; next }
    /^[ \t]*$/ && isprop { next; }
    isprop { sub(/^[ \t]*/, " "); isprop=0 } 1' CECWT.xconf >output.txt
```

Comment: Updated to show how to use sub(); but you are really not the target audience for Stack Overflow if you merely look for someone to write code for you.

Comment: Still not getting

Comment: That's not explaining how this is wrong. It works with the sample you provided. Demo: https://ideone.com/xVFHFL

Comment: Probably because you have not shared an actually valid sample.